# How do I center links in a Community page's Tile Menu?

Tags: css

I have a Community Page that has a Tile Menu, which holds 3 links that are displayed as images. For some reason, they're left-aligned, so the middle of the 3 images is to the left of the middle of the page.

I tried using the following CSS based on [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_customize_css.htm) but I don't know how to select the proper element and its content.

.forceCommunityHeadline .headlineTitleText
    {
        text-align: center;
        align-content: center;
    }

Comment: Mess with `margin: auto` or `flex:`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a tile menu where I only had 3 tiles. I was able to target them using the following in the CSS override:

.slds-large-size_1-of-4,
 .slds-large-size--1-of-4
{
    width: 33%;
}

Word of caution, this will target all tiles in your community indiscriminately if they are in a layout that allows for 4 to be visible at once. If only 3 are visible then the class will be.slds-large-size_1-of-3.

Answer (score 0):

As of Feb 2020, the tile menu element looks like the HTML in this screenshot.
[image]

You need to apply your CSS to `.tileMenuItemList` class, but it's good to reference `.forceCommunityTileMenu` to make it more specific.

text-align doesn't work here, but justify-content does because display: flex is in use.  The following CSS works, I've tested it.

```
/* Center items in a Tile Menu component */
.forceCommunityTileMenu .tileMenuItemList {
    justify-content: center;
}
```